# UIImagePickerController does not deliver geo tag data

Tags: iphone, photo, exif, geo

When I use UIImagePickerController to select a photo, either from the Camera Roll or the Photo Library, the image that gets returned to me in the method

'didFinishPickingImage'

does not contain the exif data for latitude and longitude.  I know that the headers are there, because they show up when imported into iPhoto, also if I upload images from the Camera Roll, they also contain the exif headers for location.  Is there a way to get UIImagePickerController to deliver that information as well?

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you to geotag the image received from the `UIImagePickerController`, see my answer here : 
[UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos/1967111#1967111)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is not. The UIImagePickerController incorrectly strips off the location tags, but they are there on the file (which you are not allowed to access as it's outside your sandbox).

See the discussion on Apple here: [link text](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=7668654#7668654)

And the comments on Flicker here: [link text](http://www.flickr.com/help/forum/74126/?search=exif)