# Exif and iPhone files

Tags: iphone, uiimage, exif

Im using a library for extracting EXIF data from google code.
I assume with iPhone OS 3 that you can use UIImagepicker to do it.

I just want to be able to extract the f-Stop, Shutter Speed and ISO data from the image.
I want to discard the image and just use the information that I store up.

Would I end up extracting the tag data in the viewcontroller.m or h?
This part of coding seems to baffle me a little bit and I cant figure out what to put where.
Can anyone help me out?  I still havent figured out XCode all that well.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever executable code you have needs to go in a .m (i**m**plementation) file, not a .h (**h**eader file). The headers are just for declaring things like classes, protocols, and methods, not for any real processing work.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any tutorials that you know of that explain using exif step by step?
im using the one found here -

http://iphone-land.blogspot.com/2008/06/geo-tagging-images-using-iphone-exif.html

However, for a newbie like me, its not all that thorough because im coming up with errors and i am not sure how to resolve them.

I guess im just shy in all this.  need a good place to start

Answer (score 1):

You will likely have trouble getting access to an images metadata if you get it via UIImagePickerController, due to the issues described in this question: [UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos/1720783)