# objectiveflickr geotag

Tags: iphone, flickr

I am trying to use objectiveflickr to upload an image to flickr from my iphone but for some reason it strips the EXIF info (i want the image geotagged), is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's related to this issue :

[UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos)

See my answer to this question there :
[UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos/1967111#1967111)

Comment: I cannot get iphone-exif to work, I get an error

  ".objc_class_name_EXFJpeg", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@EXFJpeg in SnapAndRunViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found


collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you add the static library (.a) of the iPhone-exif library to your project ?

Comment: Yes, I dont know why it didnt work, I put all of the .h files and the .a file and it couldnt find any of the functions. I had to go to the SVN site and download all of the .m files and add them to my project and then it worked. Have you tried using 0.9.1? maybe something is wrong with it.

Comment: I don't know which version I used exactly, but I didn't compile it on mu own. I just download the .a directly. Did you donwload the *2* .a : one for x86 (simulator) and arm (device) ? Both should be added to the project, then depending on the target, XCode the one that best match (you'd better use a different name for the 2 .a however.)