# Nil pointer returned for [exifData tagValue:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exif

I'm trying to read EXIF data from pictures taken with the apple camera's application, containning EXIF informations. I use iphone-exif library available at http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/.

My problem is that I succes getting tag informations with [exifData tagDefinition:] function :

```
EXFTag* tag = [exifData tagDefinition:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_ExposureTime]];
```

Tag information are correctly displayed in console :

> tag name :  ExposureTime
>   tag dataType :  5
>   tag ID :  33434
>   tag components :  1
>   tag adress : 0x15f900

but I can't get the tag value :

```
id value = [exifData tagValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_ExposureTime]];
```

I get nil pointer  :

> value adress : 0x0
>   value size : 4
>   value content : 0

Results are exactly the same with other tag ID like ISO Speed ratings or Focal Length.

Do I made something wrong? Is the library dysfunctional?

Raphael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the UIImagePickerController then you will not have exif data.  I tried this also.

Here is more information: [UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos/1967111#1967111)

Comment: I've tested with sourceType : Camera. And I saw that there isn't EXIF informations included.
Is it the same problem when i use sourceType : PhotoLibrary to read a picture including EXIF taken with the official Apple camera's manager?

Comment: Yes it is.  When you receive the image the EXIF data is removed from it.  I dont know why Apple would do that...

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution. As said mracoker, if I use UIImagePickerController to take pictures OR to open pictures from user's photo album, no EXIF informations are included. 
That's realy bad for my proffesional training... :'(