# How to write/get latitude longitude with image in uiimagepickercontroller?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, geolocation, uiimagepickercontroller

Currently I am saving and image with the following method in "saved photos album".

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Now I want to associate the current latitude and longitude with that image.

How can I do so ?

Can I do with its mediaInfo dictionary (metadata).

I am working in ios sdk 3.0 .

Please tell me How to get /set geo data with an image in `UIImageViewPickerController`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is not supported in iOS 4.0 and lower.

As of iOS 4.1, you can use `-[ALAssetsLibrary writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:]` to save images with metadata (untested but I assume this should work). I do not know how to format the `metadata` dictionary, though.

You should try to read some existing images that contain geodata from the assets library to check how the dictionary must be formatted.

Comment: I wish there was a corresponding one with metadata for videos.  Maybe 4.2?

Comment: Will this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos  work ? or can be rejected ?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no way for you to do using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.

However, you can use another method to save into iphone file system (but not in "saved photos album"). Then you save its metadata in another text file, going with the image path:

For PNG:

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile: uniquePath atomically: YES];
```

For JPG:

```
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: But in that case I won't be able to get that image from standard uiimagepickerviewcontrollersavedphotosalbum and I have to make my my own browser in your case i have seen the photolocations application in apple sample code which does the same thing.

Comment: yeah, I know. But seems to be no other ways yet:(

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the image from Camera, you should get the location from CLLocationManager. If you pick the image from library, you can read the location coordinates using ALAssertsLibrary:

[iPhone Get UIImagePickerController Lat/Lng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177606/iphone-get-uiimagepickercontroller-lat-lng/6454102#6454102)

After you have the location, you should be able to use exif library to save the data with the image.

Comment: The problem with this is that between taking the photo and touching "Use Photo", the location of the phone can change. So we cannot reliably determine the location of the phone at the time the photo was taken by this method.

Answer (score 0):

you cant get latitude and longitude from image what comes from uiimagepickercontroller. It seems apple striping exif tags (i guess for privacy reasons).

Comment: see the above answer it is possible in 4.1

Comment: yeh, but 4.1 is way too young for deployment imo