# Images latitude and longitude like "Places" iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to find out what are the coordinates of a photo chosen from the photo library via "UIImagePickerController".

I present the imagePickerController:

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];
```

and then:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    selectedImage.image = image;
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I looked in the documentation about the "editingInfo" dictionary but I think is not the right way.
Help me please!
Thank all very much!

Oscar

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778519/how-to-write-get-latitude-longitude-with-image-in-uiimagepickercontroller and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177606/iphone-get-uiimagepickercontroller-lat-lng/6454102#6454102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at this [so-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos). This should be done with the [asset-lib-framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

`imagePickerController:didFinishPickingImage:editingInfo:` is deprecated, you should use `- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` instead, although I don't believe it'll help you getting the coordinates (`info` contains the `UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata` key, but documentation says it only works when source is set to `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`).
If you want to get the coordinates where a photo was shot you need to use [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730), but will require to make your own picker (retrieve and arrange assets on your own, there should be some examples out there on how to do this). You can either use the `valueForProperty:` method from `ALAsset` class, or the `metadata` method from `ALAssetRepresentation` (which I believe returns a `NSDictionary` with the keys listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageProperties_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005103)