# Add EXIF metadata to a UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, exif

I need to add EXIF metadata to a `UIImage` taken either from the camera or an album, then save the image to an album. How can I do this?

To take the photo I use:

```
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
```

but I don't know how to add EXIF data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos May help