# How can I get date information from a UIImage or a picture in Cocoa?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image, date

When a user picks a photo from an iPhone's camera roll, I can access the photo's date and time information.

How can I get the date information from an arbitrary UIImage or a picture in Cocoa Touch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 4 you can use the UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata to fetch the data. There's some [Example Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoLocations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008909) by Apple. The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos) might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its Working fine:

```
-(void)dateInfo
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    //--- Listing file by name sort
    NSLog(@"\n File list %@",fileList);




    int num;
    //-- Listing file name with modified dated
    for (NSString *s in fileList)
    {
        NSString *filestring = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",s];

        NSDictionary *filePathsArray1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filestring error:nil];
        NSString *modifiedDate = [filePathsArray1 objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
        NSLog(@"\n Modified Day : %@", modifiedDate);

        num=num+1;
    }
}
```