# When converting UIImage to Base64, exif information is not included/removed

Tags: ios, swift, image, base64, alamofire

So Im trying to upload images from photo library to a server with `alamofire` post method, the uploading parts is working. However it's when I convert the `UIImage` to `Base64` before uploading that stripes/removes all the exif information from the image.

Before converting the `UIImage` to `Base64` all exif information is there and accessible but after the conversion the exif information is removed. I have tried uploading a `Base64` of the same `UIImage` but converted on a website and that kept the exif information, that proves that the problem is with the swift version of the conversion.

Here is what the converting part of the code looks like:

```
func imageTobase64(image: UIImage) -> String {
        var base64String = ""
        let  cim = CIImage(image: image)
        if (cim != nil) {
            let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
            base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
        }
        return base64String
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write exif metadata to an image (not the camera roll, just a UIImage or JPEG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006759/how-to-write-exif-metadata-to-an-image-not-the-camera-roll-just-a-uiimage-or-j)

Comment: @mag_zbc Im looking for an answer in swift and the problem Im facing is different from the one in your comment. Thanks for the comment anyway.

Comment: Your question is answered there, in the first line of the accepted answer - _UIImage does not contain metadata information_