# UIImagePickerController saving image with geolocation info?

Tags: ios, gps, uiimagepickercontroller

When I take the picture using the UIImagePickerController I get the info dictionary in the delegate method call didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.... that does not provide any information on the location of the image...

I want to be able to embed the location where the image was taken and possibly even the heading... How can I save the image with the location embedded in it as well?

Answer (score 2):

iOS strips the geolocation data from images.  You will have to use CoreLocation to replace the stripped data.  See the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5294574/239318).

Comment: The problem is that there is no such key in the dictionary I get from the delegate. the first log prints out the info dictionary, but the second log prints out null... so it seems like the key "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" does not exist... - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSLog(@"UIImagePicker did finish pickingMedia info dict: %@", info);
    NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL--> %@", [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]);
}     Any suggestion?

Comment: @Blip added an equivalent link.

Answer (score 0):

Look at RonC's answer here:
[UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos)

This shows how to get the location / date from the ALAssetLibrary API. For photos taken by the camera I haven't found a ready-made solution yet but clearly you can just use your own CLLocationManager to fetch the current location.