# How to set the location for the captured photo by using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, photos

I would like to see my captured picture by using `UIImagePickerController` in Photos app with the geo tagging (Where the picture has taken).

While capturing a snap by using `UIImagePickerController`, I would like to tag the current location for the captured picture, such that when it get saved to `PhotoLibrary`, it should show  on the map in the Photos (Standard app to show the photos/videos) app.
Could anyone has any idea, how the Photos app internal mechanism to show the photos/videos on the map.

Comment: +1 I also want to know how to do that

Comment: I hope it helps:

[UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos

Cheers!
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the location data requires a bit of work to find.

The delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

will give you an `info` dictionary, containing some metadata for the image. This blog has a nice log dump of the typical content:

http://jomnius.blogspot.dk/2011/01/what-is-inside-uiimagepickercontrollerm.html

Based on the full path to the image (found in the `info` dictionary), you can however dig up the lat and long using `ALAssetsLibrary`

This blog explains the process in detail:

http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/getting-metadata-from-images-on-ios/