# Using iphone-exif for EXIF data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exif, libexif

I want to use [iphone-exif library](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/) for EXIF data in my proj. But i dont know if i done any mistake or not it gives error like

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXFJpeg", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

please give some solution for that.
Thanks in advance for ur answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using that library Please go through this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller/9890442#9890442)

Actually I had the same problem so I had created it for myself for getting EXIF info purpose..

Answer (score 3):

When you download iPhone-exif your will find two precompiles libraries.

1. Release-iphoneos/libiphone-exif.a
2. Release-simulator-iphonesimulator/libiphone-exif.a

Depending on where you'd like to run your app, you need to link against the right file.
You probably added Release-iphoneos/libiphone-exif.a to your project and then you tried to run in on the Simulator (i386 architecture!).

Easiest way:
Create a universal library of the both above.

1. Open terminal
2. Cd to your iphone-ex download folder (`cd iphone-exif-0-9`)
3. `lipo -arch i386 Release-simulator-iphonesimulator/libiphone-exif.a -arch armv6 Release-iphoneos/libiphone-exif.a -create -output libiphone-exif-universal.a`
4. add the file "`libiphone-exif-universal.a`" to your Xcode project

But i've just found out that there is a armv7 build missing. If you'd like to place your app on the appstore you once need also to build the library also for armv7 (out of the sources!)