# How do you get a UIImage's geographic coordinates?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gps, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I get the GPS coordinates of a UIImage after the picture was taken in a UIImagePickerController? Does the image contain the coordinates in it's metadata or should I create a class for the image and its coordinates and save that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Please try to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller/9890442#9890442) and do as said in that answer..

I had done that and got success..

Hope It works for you..

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can access the metadata of an image right after you take the picture. The protocol method that is called by the system after an image has been selected is,

```
(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

The NSDictionary argument, info, contains a key: UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata

AFAIK, You will need **CLLocationManager** to get the current location and geotag it.

Answer (score 1):

From **iOS 8** onwards you can use [Photos Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11682617/how-do-you-get-a-uiimages-geographic-coordinates).

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
  let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL
        if url != nil {

            let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [url!], options: nil)
            let asset = fetchResult.firstObject
            print(asset?.location?.coordinate.latitude)
            print(asset?.creationDate)
        }
}
```