# How to check an image selected is panorama image or not?

Tags: ios, iphone

i am using UIImagePicker to get an image from the library. I just want to hide panorama library. Is there any option for hide this library in UIImagePicker.Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not you check the width of pics

Comment: but kindly tell me what is maximum or minimum width and height of panorama pic.

Comment: if you are taking form the device then it will be just greater then the screen resolution .and if it is equal or small then it will be not . hope you understand

Comment: yes got it but when we get from web or gallery then how we identify.

Comment: But this can't check if it is a web image downloaded from elsewhere.

Comment: This may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744404/how-to-check-a-image-selected-is-panorama-image-or-not

Answer (score 1):

A panorama is just a picture with a large ratio between width and height (or vice versa).

There is no minimum or maximum (OK, there might be a maximum) size.

The ratio of a standard photo is around `4:3` (from the iPhone camera) so you could find the ratio and determine whether or not it is a panorama.

Something like...

```
CGFloat smallest = MIN(image.size.width, image.size.height);
CGFloat largest = MAX(image.size.width, image.size.height);

CGFloat ratio = largest/smallest;

CGFloat maximumRatioForNonePanorama = 4 / 3; // set this yourself depending on 

if (ratio > maximumRatioForNonePanorama) {
    // it is probably a panorama
}
```

However, also note that when taking a panorama you can start it a stop it without moving the camera at all so it will just be a standard photo.

This is why you have to use the ratio like this. There isn't a flag you can rely on (I think).