# iOS | How to identify a panoramic image programatically

Tags: ios, swift, panoramas

Is there any method or technique to identify a bitmap (png/jpeg) is actually a 360 degree panoramic image or a normal image. What is the mechanism to distinguish panoramic image from normal image in swift for iOS.

Comment: Look into `PHAsset` and its `mediaSubtypes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A panorama is just a picture with a large ratio between width and height (or vice versa).

There is no minimum size but there would be a maximum(Probably).

The ratio of a standard photo is around 4:3 so you could find the ratio and determine whether or not it is a panorama.

You can do something like :

```
let smallest = min(image.size.width, image.size.height)
let largest = max(image.size.width, image.size.height)

let ratio = largest/smallest

let maximumRatioForNonePanorama = 4 / 3 // check with your ratio 

if ratio > maximumRatioForNonePanorama {
    // it is probably a panorama
}
```

But, also note that when capturing a panorama you can start it a stop it without moving the camera at all so it can just be a normal photo.

This is why you have to use the ratio like this.I think there's not a flag for this(Yet).

Comment: @Cristik If this does'nt help you, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744404/how-to-check-a-image-selected-is-panorama-image-or-not)

Comment: Ohh Sorry @Nico If this does'nt help you, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744404/how-to-check-a-image-selected-is-panorama-image-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

panorama images have different resolution their ratio will be **2:1** ,**4:1** and **10:1**. To identify panorama image use below code snippet

```
 let smallest = min(YOUR_IMAGE.size.width, YOUR_IMAGE.size.height)
 let largest = max(YOUR_IMAGE.size.width, YOUR_IMAGE.size.height)
 let ratio = largest/smallest
 if (ratio >= CGFloat(2/1)) || (ratio >= CGFloat(4/1)) || (ratio >= CGFloat(10/1)) {

    // Panorama image

 } else {

    //NON -Panorama image 

 }
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

`PHAsset` has a property named `mediaSubtypes`. Just check if this array contains panorama subtype.

```
if mediaSubtypes.contains(.photoPanorama) {
    // ...
}
```