# Geo-Location information in iphone pictures

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, geolocation, exif

I am trying to make an app which can map pictures from photo library of iphone to google map. I am trying to extract the longitude and latitude information from images. I referred this [Get Exif data from UIImage - UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller) guide and successfully retrieve exif data but it does not contain the latitude and longitude information. It gave me the following output
    `exif_dict: {
    ApertureValue = "2.52606882168926";
    BrightnessValue = "3.144031311154599";
    ColorSpace = 1;
    ComponentsConfiguration =     (
        1,
        2,
        3,
        0
    );
    DateTimeDigitized = "2014:10:25 13:31:21";
    DateTimeOriginal = "2014:10:25 13:31:21";
    ExifVersion =     (
        2,
        2,
        1
    );
    ExposureMode = 0;
    ExposureProgram = 2;
    ExposureTime = "0.008333333333333333";
    FNumber = "2.4";
    Flash = 32;
    FlashPixVersion =     (
        1,
        0
    );
    FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 35;
    FocalLength = "3.85";
    ISOSpeedRatings =     (
        320
    );
    LensMake = Apple;
    LensModel = "iPhone 4 front camera 3.85mm f/2.4";
    LensSpecification =     (
        "3.85",
        "3.85",
        "2.4",
        "2.4"
    );
    MeteringMode = 5;
    PixelXDimension = 640;
    PixelYDimension = 480;
    SceneCaptureType = 0;
    SceneType = 1;
    SensingMethod = 2;
    ShutterSpeedValue = "6.909195402298851";
    SubsecTimeDigitized = 616;
    SubsecTimeOriginal = 616;
    WhiteBalance = 0;
}`

Please help me to retrieve longitude and latitude information. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the photo was taken with location services enabled for the camera app? If location services were disabled, there will be no geolocation information in the photo metadata.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline To verify further I looked into the maps through photos and It shows the location where the photo was taken correctly

Comment: Any answer to this question, I am having the same issue with missing location EXIF data but I can see the location in Google Photos...