# Print EXIF data from UIImagePickerController in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, exif

I'm currently working on a photo app written in Swift. I'm having a problem getting the EXIF data from the photos. I found some tutorials here but couldn't find one in Swift that worked for me. Here is my code:

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)

    //Assign image to a variable
    selectedImage = image


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    println("finished")
}
```

How can I get the EXIF data (specifically, the GPS data) from the UIImage? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Exif data from UIImage - UIImagePickerController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller)