# How to write exif data with GPS location to uiimage on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gps, exif

I want to write exif data with GPS location to uiimage on iPhone.
I googled for this and i found libiPhone-exif.a libarary for iPhone but it is not working for armv7 architecture xcode project.
I also tried using ALAssetsLibrary functions suggested on following link
[Get Exif data from UIImage - UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766394/get-exif-data-from-uiimage-uiimagepickercontroller/9890442#9890442)

I am able to get exif data from UIImagePickerController using above code and i want to write it to UIIMage with NSData.
And I also want to know whehter the exif data Will be preserved after compressing UIImage using following statement,

```
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img,1.0);
```

Please help me to write exif data with GPS location to uiimage on iPhone

Comment: for iOS 8? or u have to support iOS 7 also?

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi Yes for iOS 7 and above versions please help me if you have some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some exif data(like GPS location) will be lost when you try to turn NSData to UIImage,because UIImage class doesn't contain these infos.You can only get from NSData.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem with you in my previous project, you cannot write GPS info to UIImage, you have to use NSData or save image.jpg or png somewhere to keep GPS information.