# EXIF data read and write

Tags: swift, exif

I searched for getting the EXIF data from picture files and write them back for Swift. But I only could find predefied libs for different languages.

I also found references to "CFDictionaryGetValue", but which keys do I need to get the data? And how can I write it back?

Comment: There is already a `swift` tag. What is the point of including that in the question title?

Comment: Ok, I wanted to indicate that language matters. I will not use it in future.

Comment: Sure, I take what I can get. :-) I will see how far I get with it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm using this to *get* EXIF infos from an image file:

```
import ImageIO

let fileURL = theURLToTheImageFile
if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, nil) {
    let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)
    if let dict = imageProperties as? [String: Any] {
        print(dict)
    }
}
```

It gives you a dictionary containing various informations like the color profile - the EXIF info specifically is in `dict["{Exif}"]`.

Comment: How could I write the EXIF data back to the image?

Comment: this answer didn't mention "write", anyone knows it?

Comment: @Amos See https://stackoverflow.com/q/37992611/2227743 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43920643/2227743 it looks like you can use these Q&A to find out how to write the exif.

Comment: You can also user _kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary_ as key.

Answer (score 11):

Swift 4

```
extension UIImage {
    func getExifData() -> CFDictionary? {
        var exifData: CFDictionary? = nil
        if let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            data.withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>)->Void in
                if let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, data.count) {
                    let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(cfData, nil)
                    exifData = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source!, 0, nil)
                }
            }
        }
        return exifData
    }
}
```

Swift 5

```
extension UIImage {

    func getExifData() -> CFDictionary? {
        var exifData: CFDictionary? = nil
        if let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            data.withUnsafeBytes {
                let bytes = $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
                if let cfData = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, bytes, data.count), 
                    let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(cfData, nil) {
                    exifData = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil)
                }
            }
        }
        return exifData
    }
}
```

Comment: For Swift 5+ you want to change the `data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>)->Void in ...` to `data.withUnsafeBytes { let bytes = $0.baseAddress?.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self) ... }`

Comment: This method retrieves less exif data than the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

You can use AVAssetExportSession to write metadata.

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: existingUrl)
let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exportSession?.outputURL = newURL
exportSession?.metadata = [
  // whatever [AVMetadataItem] you want to write
]
exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {
  // respond to file writing completion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
extension Data { // for UIImage.data only

    var metadata: [AnyHashable : Any]? {
        let options = [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality : NSNumber(value: 1),
                                         kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha : kCFBooleanTrue,
                                        kCGImageSourceShouldCache : kCFBooleanFalse] as CFDictionary
        guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(self as CFData, options) else { return nil }
        return CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, options) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
    }
}
```

Any `image` can use it as

```
    guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1),
          var metadata = data.metadata
    else {
        return nil
    }
    EXIF -> metadata[kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary] as? [AnyHashable : Any] 
    TIFF -> metadata[kCGImagePropertyTIFFDictionary] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
    GPS -> metadata[kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
    & etc.
```

Do whatever you want with this changeable dictionary.

Comment: How is this different from existing answers?

Comment: @matt, it is shorter and useful for other subdictionaries besides EXIF