# How to set the location for the captured photo by using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

How to set the location for the captured photo by using UIImagePickerController?

I have an app that has the option to take a photo or grab one from the phones gallery.
If I selsct one from the gallery I can see the GPS data in the info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL], but when I save it to the apps documents folder it loses the GPS data.
If I take a photo from within the app the info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] is nil?

Answer (score 1):

I did lots of RND and searched here and there and tried many solutions but no luck, after googling for hours

Finally figured out with the help of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest?language=objc

```
public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true)
    self.imageToSave = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    try? PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChangesAndWait {
        let imgReq = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: self.imageToSave!)
        imgReq.location = self.location
        imgReq.isFavorite = true
     }
}
```

Comment: The documentation for this library has to be some of Apple's worst, thanks for figuring this out

Answer (score 0):

So, I assuming you want to fetch Metadata Information -
Try the following snippet for this-
[Get UIImage MetaData](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42862356/7010352)