# Getting picture data from iOS photo gallery

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

I need to get metadata (EXIF and other) from images stored in the iOS photo gallery. Therefore I need the original picture data instead of an UIImage object.

At the moment I get the asset-image url using imagepickercontroll and ALAssetsLibrary as described here: [display image from URL retrieved from ALAsset in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837115/display-image-from-url-retrieved-from-alasset-in-iphone)

This url can be used to get an UIImage object but how can I get the original image so that I can process it's metadata?

Regards,

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos

Comment: Thanks for the link. Access to the "raw" file data seems only possible using the mentioned private API trick described in the linked post.

Answer (score 2):

ALAssetsLibrary to retrieve all images [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=kGy77H7ejY0C&pg=PT508&lpg=PT508&dq=alassetslibrary+erica+sadun+ios+cookbook&source=bl&ots=S_8m7UjbMb&sig=2eeuAG8xBFGK2k1VtEdcRUgzF7o&hl=en#v=onepage&q=alassetslibrary%20erica%20sadun%20ios%20cookbook&f=false)

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library assetForURL:assetURL
resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)  {
    NSDictionary *metadata = asset.defaultRepresentation.metadata;
    imageMetadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:metadata];
    [self addEntriesFromDictionary:metadata];
}
failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
}];
[library autorelease];
```

Refer more [getting-metadata-from-images-on-ios](http://blog.codecropper.com/2011/05/getting-metadata-from-images-on-ios/) link and get helped.

Comment: Thanks. But I do need the original file data. It seems, as mentioned in the link Ben posted, that this is only possible with private API.

Comment: check edited answer http://books.google.co.in/books?id=kGy77H7ejY0C&pg=PT508&lpg=PT508&dq=alassetslibrary+erica+sadun+ios+cookbook&source=bl&ots=S_8m7UjbMb&sig=2eeuAG8xBFGK2k1VtEdcRUgzF7o&hl=en#v=onepage&q=alassetslibrary%20erica%20sadun%20ios%20cookbook&f=false