# How to give custom name to a picture in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming. Does anyone know how to give custom name to a picture which was taken using the mobile camera? After that the picture has to be saved along with that name in the photo gallery.

Can anyone figure out a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **MetaData** to **UIImage**. Same metadata of UIImage can be used to know images's information.

Refer [Get Exif data from UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967111/1106035).

Refer [UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1967111/1106035)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.
Because `iOS` saves it with a `asseturl`.
You can't add your meta data along with an image in the photolibrary.
And you can only access the photo using assets library.