# Adding EXIF tag 'ImageUniqueID' to an image

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocoa-touch, exif, javax.imageio

I've had some great success adding EXIF data to an images captured from the UIImagePickerControl...Mostly following the examples from other questions. i.e.

1. [UIImagePickerController and extracting EXIF data from existing photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos)
2. [Problem setting exif data for an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125323/problem-setting-exif-data-for-an-image)

BUT I've never managed to (set and then later retreive) the ImageUniqueID tag (kCGImagePropertyExifImageUniquID)

I've tried vairous combinations:

```
NSMutableDictionary *EXIFDictionary = [[[metadataAsMutable objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary]mutableCopy]autorelease];

[EXIFDictionary setObject:@"1234" forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifImageUniquID];

//[EXIFDictionary setObject[NSNumber numberWithInt:1234] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifImageUniquID];

[metadataAsMutable setObject:EXIFDictionary forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary];

//then save the mutable data back to Image
```

All the other EXIF, TIFF, and IPTC keys I set using this method are succesfully saved and then retrieved later using similar methods.

Any Idea how to set this value?

Comment: can't using the Linux 'exif' tool either, here's the error: "jcomeau@aspire:~$ exif --ifd=EXIF --tag=0xa420 --set-value=0x1234 -o has_id.jpg peaceful_coexistence.jpg 
Setting a value for this tag is unsupported!"