# UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata is storing different data compared to the built in iOS camera

Tags: ios, geolocation, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, exif

I am using UIImagePickerController to capture an image from camera. The app, which I am developing requires to read the metadata of the image just captured, especially its gps information. 
I am getting the metadata of the image from dictionary passed to the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
 NSString *mediaType = [info
                           objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
        NSMutableDictionary *imgInfo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];
        NSLog(@"Image Metadata : %@",imgInfo);
        //Passing the imgInfo to other methods for further processing.
    }
}
```

But in the logs I noticed that the metadata does not contains the gps information of the image, also some of the EXIF data is missing when compared with a photo taken by the regular iOS camera.

Why the metadata returned by UIImagePickerController is different from the metadata of image taken by regular ios camera?
And how can I get the complete metadata of the image including the gps information?

Comment: Easy, just take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1238838/uiimagepickercontroller-and-extracting-exif-data-from-existing-photos