# How to get image complete data while sharing it with the help of share extension?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using share extension in my application and I want to show image taken time while I am sharing image with share extension.Is there any way to get the time of image when we use share extension.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp is available in EXIF data stored with the images. You can get it using UIImagePickerController like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33672661/4042468

On the other hand, if you have image file url, you can use `import ImageIO` and the below code to get all the properties of the image of which date time is one.

```
if let imagePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "test", ofType: "jpg") {
        let imageURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath)

        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageURL, nil) {
            if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as? [String: AnyObject] {

            }
        }
    }
```

Note that there is a Exif key in which you can find timestamp.

Comment: i am not using image picker controller i share image direct from gallery so i want time of the image

Comment: @DeepakSaki Have a look now.

Comment: is it possible with the help of asset url because i share image direct from gallery. asset url is not passed in file path.